# Is is possible to bind a key plus a variable in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have buffers named `*terminal<1>*`, `*terminal<2>*`, `*terminal<3>*`, etc. Is there a way to bind a key combination that will take an argument for the number? That is, I want to bind `C-c 1` to switch to `*terminal<1>*` and `C-c 2` to switch to `*terminal<2>*`, and so on. If I can't do this directly, is it possible to do metaprogramming in Elisp that will define all the functions for me?

Comment: here's a nice tutorial on command arguments: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind keys as usual:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c 1") (lambda () 
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*terminal<1>*")))
```

To create all the shortcuts from 1 to 9 we would use [macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Macros.html).

**edit:** This buggy version may put you on tracks. I give up :(

```
(defmacro gototerminal (count)
`(global-set-key (kbd ,(concat "C-c " (number-to-string count))) 
;; with the comma I want to evaluate what is inside concat
(lambda ()   (interactive) 
   (switch-to-buffer (concat "*terminal<"  ,count ">*"))))
 )

(progn (setq count 1)
          (while (< count 10)
            (gototerminal count)
            (setq count (1+ count))
            ))
```

ps: an elisp debugger is edebug. Set it with C-u C-M-x

Comment: I had something going similar to your version before you posted it. I'll continue to tweak it and post the result.

Answer (score 3):

In this suggestion, the interactive `switch-to-terminal` will take either a prefix argument `C-u 2` for example, or prompt the user.

The macro then makes setting up the key bindings a little easier.

Finally I bind `C-c 1` to `C-c 4` to switch to `*terminal<1>*` to `*terminal<4>*`.

```
(defun switch-to-terminal (buf-num)
  (interactive "NNumber of buffer to visist: ")
  (let* ((buf-name (format "*terminal<%d>*" buf-num))
         (buf (get-buffer buf-name)))
    (unless buf
      (error "No buffer %s" buf-name))
    (switch-to-buffer buf)))

(defmacro bind-switch-to-terminal (num)
  `(global-set-key
    ,(kbd (format "C-c %d" num))
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (switch-to-terminal ,num))))

(bind-switch-to-terminal 1)
(bind-switch-to-terminal 2)
(bind-switch-to-terminal 3)
(bind-switch-to-terminal 4)
```

This change uses the same `switch-to-terminal` function, but replaces `bind-switch-to-terminal` with a function.  The `lexical-let*` allows for the creation of a closure to create unique terminal switching functions, the `dotimes` loop then binds for `C-c 1` to `C-c 9`.

```
(defun bind-switch-to-terminal (num)
  (lexical-let* ((buf-num num)
                 (switch-func
                  (lambda ()
                    (interactive)
                    (switch-to-terminal buf-num))))
    (global-set-key
     (kbd (format "C-c %d" buf-num))
     switch-func)))

(dotimes (num 9)
  (bind-switch-to-terminal (1+ num)))
```

Comment: Andrew, yours is the more complete working answer, but Ehvince beat you to it with a partial answer that led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function that calls `interactive` with an `n` argument which indicates that the function reads a number from the mini buffer:

```
(defun test (x)
     (interactive "nNumber of buffer to visit: ")
     (message (concat "received number: " (number-to-string x))))
```

Binding this to a key will let you enter a number in the mini buffer.

Another way is to use a numerical argument:

```
(defun test (x)
     (interactive "P")
     (message (concat "received number: " (number-to-string x))))
```

Say you bind this function to `C-c c`, you can then pass it the number 2 as an argument by pressing `C-u 2 C-c c`.

Comment: While I appreciate having these two approaches to consider, they both require more key strokes than I was hoping for. The interactive function requires hitting Enter after the number. `C-u 2 C-c c` is even longer. I'd rather manually define 9 functions that have to constantly make extra key strokes.

Comment: FWIW, use `(interactive "NTerminal number: ")` ("N" instead of "n"), and it'll combine those two approaches, bypassing the prompt if there's a numeric prefix arg. Also, `M-2 C-c c` is a bit quicker to type.

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid the usage of an existing prefix key like <kbd>C-c</kbd> you can trigger a command with one keypress e.g. <kbd>F9</kbd>.
This command can have a single key as input.

Example:

```lisp
(defun test (k)
  (interactive "K")
  (message "Pressed key: %d" (- (aref k 0) ?0)))

(local-set-key [f9] 'test)
```